# In a similiar condition "as"?

Tags: prepositions, comparison

Is it correct to use *as* in the context like:

> Prague is in a similiar climate **as** Michigan.

I know things tend to be similiar *to* something else but it sounds odd to me here.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if *as* is correct. I would rephrase it to

> Prague has a similiar climate **to** Michigan.
>
> Prague and Michigan are similar **in** climate.